# How long can a person be kept in a Carbonite so that they can be successfully revitalized? Do people age within it?

Tags: star-wars

There is evidence of several creatures being frozen in carbonite and later "woken up" without any permanent consequences (as far as I know).

**Is it safe to assume that carbonite-freezing is form of cryo-stasis? Is there any limit to how long can person be frozen in carbonite and still be defrosted and live after that?**

I am not really sure if carbonite freezing is really freezing (in the terms of being sustained at deep subzero temperature) with all biological functions "paused", or just form of "imprisonment" with biological functions slowed down. Simply, do people age in carbonite?

Comment: As vital life functions work, ageing is inevitable. But, it's rate would be very very low.

Comment: On the other hand, Anakin, Rex and others used carbonite to freeze themselves in order to infiltrate Separatist prison. Their life signs were not detected by separatist droids, should I take it that their life signs were super low, or is it possible they just weren't any? (I assume that working vital life functions produce life signs.)

Comment: There are life signs which can be read at the side of the carbonite block.
@Delltar you should mention if you want a canon or legends answer.

Answer (score 4):

The Jedi Knight [Roni von Wasaki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Roni_von_Wasaki) (from the non-canon RPG sourcebook [Challenge 66](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Disturbance_in_the_Force_%28article%29)") was frozen in carbonite for 20,000 years.

Although it drove him insane, he did not age a day.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A footnote in the new canon novelisation of Star Wars: Return of the Jedi offers the following information:

> ***Before the invention of the hyperdrive, some space travelers used carbonite to endure long voyages.** But the side effects are brutal. Since a common side effect was death, Solo is lucky to have only exhaustion, weakness, dehydration, dizziness, memory loss, and blindness*
>
> <sub><sup>[Return of the Jedi: Beware the Power of the Dark Side!](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi:_Beware_the_Power_of_the_Dark_Side!)</sup></sub>

Assuming hyperspace travel is the only way to reach supralight speeds (and that star systems in the Star Wars galaxy are similary distant to our own galaxy), it follows that Carbonite freezing can be used for **multi-year voyages**, albeit at the user's risk.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the amount of time it would take to kill them, but i know that they wouldn't age at all due to the fact that they are frozen, and therefore only half- alive, so they can't age or even think while frozen.

Comment: And how do you know all of this? Was this explained in a book? Comic? Interview? First hand experience?

Comment: So...if they don't age "at all" (Which is impossible, even in cryostasis), why would they die?

Comment: Some sources vaguely imply, that person is not frozen in carbonite like in ice, there is no actual freezing (sub-zero temperature etc). Other sources say carbonite can slow down body functions dramaticly.
Bottom line – canon is very vague in this I think :)